# Unable to get changes that are in git repo into TFS with git-tfs

Tags: git-tfs

We use TFS for our source control system, but need to work with a contractor. We've set up a GitHub repo and I've been using `git-tfs` to move changes between the two. I'm not very familiar with git, and have managed to get myself into some trouble.

The git repo was in sync with the TFS repo. The contractor pushed a few commits to GitHub. After that, I checked in a few changes to TFS, then performed a `git-tfs pull` followed by syncing with GitHub (through the GitHub for Window application).

The changes I recently checked into TFS are in the GitHub repo. The changes from the contractor are in the GitHub repo and in my local repo, and I'm trying to get them into TFS. When I run `git-tfs checkintool`, I get:

```
Working with tfs remote: default
Basing from parent 'default:11102', use -i to override
Nothing to checkin!
```

If I run `git-tfs rcheckin`, I get the following. This shows the changes I'm trying to get into TFS, but notice the message at the bottom `The item $/RDi/Software/System/SZ-Working3/EmbeddedGui is not a branch of $/RDi/Software/System/SZ-Working3/EmbeddedGui.`. I think this is the problem, but I'm not sure how to rectify it.

```
Working with tfs remote: default
Basing from parent 'default:11102', use -i to override
Fetching changes from TFS to minimize possibility of late conflict...
Working on the merge commit: d2a85cd7b88715cabc6ed6cf5b9b7b5fc60359e0
Starting checkin of d2a85cd7 'Merge commit 'd36d26a6c6af5c1e89cf4dc7b2634964827b3ded'

Updated port screen PSD files. Should have what contractor needs regarding the animated arrows.

Replace language PSD files with new ones - the new ones contain the button pressed state for the OK/Cancel buttons.

Remove test file.

swiping removed from language page

Worked on issue 25: RemoteLib locks up when network settings update.

yes/no button added on language page'
 edit .git\~w\QtJson/JObject.h
 edit .git\~w\qml.qrc
 add rsrc/images/480x272/common/no-small.png
 add rsrc/images/480x272/common/yes-small.png
 add rsrc/images/800x480/common/no-small.png
 add rsrc/images/800x480/common/yes-small.png
 edit .git\~w\rsrc/qml/pages/MetricsPage.qml
 edit .git\~w\rsrc/qml/pages/RegionalSettingsEditorPage.qml
The item $/RDi/Software/System/SZ-Working3/EmbeddedGui is not a branch of $/RDi/Software/System/SZ-Working3/EmbeddedGui.
The item $/RDi/Software/System/SZ-Working3/EmbeddedGui is not a branch of $/RDi/Software/System/SZ-Working3/EmbeddedGui.
```

Comment: Which version of git-tfs are you running?

Comment: @fedepad git-tfs version 0.21.0.0 (TFS client library 12.0.0.0 (MS)) (64-bit)